# How to get the thermistor with the lowest resistance?

Tags: thermistor

My ASUS motherboard has one thermistor connector that takes a 10 kΩ thermistor.

I want to connect 2 or 3 thermistors to this connector but only the one with the lowest resistance to be read by the motherboard.

Is this possible? If yes, then what would be the best approach? So far I tried larger thermistors in parallel but that is not accurate.

The chip is an [NCT6796D](https://www.nuvoton.com/resource-files/NCT6796D_Datasheet_V0_6.pdf).

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fsYQNg.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fiwELu.png)</sup>

---

I am thinking to try an Arduino.
I'm trying to figure out how to make a potentiometer with it.

 Maybe this will work:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fYypBi.png)</sup>

Comment: Sorry, but generally, questions asking if something is possible are not very good; because everything is possible unless some restriction prevents it, such as laws of physics.

Comment: It depends on what sort of circuit is being used to read the thermistor. If there is a current being passed through it to read a voltage, then [this Q/A](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390355/pick-largest-of-several-voltages-with-analogue-comparators) can be modified to provide a solution to picking the smallest voltage. If OTOH the circuit is using the thermistor as the feedback R in an RC oscillator to count frequency, or in a Wheatstone bridge, then it's maybe impossible, certainly more complicated. Post the schematic of the measuring circuit.

Comment: Now the additional requirement is that it must be the best way. That is also very subjective, and you don't define what best means to you. Likely you don't even want the best solution but just a good enough solution. But please understand that ways to do it depends on how the motherboard uses the thermistor, and it is currently unknown. Do you have the schematics of the motherboard, or can you reverse-engineer how the motherboard uses the thermistor?

Comment: When you say “lowest” do you mean lowest temperature or lowest resistance? These are commonly NTC thermistors so those two conditions are opposite

Comment: Not possible in any simple way.

Comment: @Drew define 'simple'

Comment: What are trying to do?

Comment: Chris - Hi, You wrote an "answer" but it seems it wasn't the answer to your original question. It was additional information, so it has been added to your question as an edit (i.e. an update) instead. Unless you are writing the *full and final* answer to your own question (i.e. unless you have solved the problem yourself and don't need further help) please don't use the box labeled "Your Answer" below. Instead please edit the question to add new information & clarifications. (This is one way that Stack Exchange differs from forums. Please see the [tour] and [help] for more rules.) Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a variation of the answer from Neil_UK, where I (ab-)use a LM339 comparator with open collector outputs. This way no diodes are needed and the sense voltage can be as low as ~0.2V.

There is a separate reference IC just in case the mainboard reference cannot  provide the additional current.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fLmbPd.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

As Neil_UK mentioned in a comment, using a comparator this way has a high risk of oscillations and stability problems. I soldered this circuit and indeed it needs a capacitor (here C3) at the output as mentioned in figure 11 of the [LM339 datasheet from ST](https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/datasheet/bf/7e/d7/a4/67/86/4e/89/CD00000460.pdf/files/CD00000460.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00000460.pdf). The output low voltage is clipping at 30 mV.
It is possible to keep the NTC on the mainboard.

I simulated the circuit with LTSpice. The different NTC values are replaced by two sine generators with different frequencies and amplitudes. The output (green track) shows the min(a,b) function.

[image: Analog_UMin]

Comment: Can I power the lm339 with 2v from the MCP1501? Can I use LM4040 instead of MCP1501?

Comment: @Chris No, LM339 will probably not work with 2V in this circuit. It needs some headroom (1.5V) between maximum input voltage and VCC. So 3.3 V may be just sufficient. Yes, the shunt regulator LM4040 will work as well. It was indeed my first idea, but I was too lazy to create a schematic symbol for it.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how lm339 works. Does it output the voltage that is larger or the voltage that is smaller?

Comment: @Chris The datasheet shows a simplified inner circuit. There is only an NPN at the output, that can sink current. No source current comes out of it. In some aspects like an OpAmp with a missing upper output transistor.

Comment: I see the NPN transistor. I guess there should be no worries to power it at a voltage higher than 2V.

Comment: Will the NPN transistor reproduce the same resistance as the thermistor? and will the comparators with higher input voltage have the output NPN disabled?

Comment: @Chris Yes, that is the idea behind it. Look at my simulator output, one comparator works with the red input voltage and one works with the blue. The green shows the combined output and you see, that always the lower value of red and blue is produced. There is a vertical offset between red/blue and green, but if you move the green track down in mind you will see what I mean.

Comment: I see now that the Vout follows the lower curve of the two input but on graph when Vin is ~0.7V the Vout is ~1.7V. Shouldn't the Vout be the same as Vin or this is just for visualization and in real situation there is no offset?

Comment: @Chris I cannot simulate an NTC, so I used AC voltages and capacitors (C1 and C2). This produces the voltage differences in the graphics. The voltages across the simulated NTCs R2 and R5 swing around 1 VDC as the green track does.

Comment: I noticed that that you used AC sources for testing. I feel confident now that this will work really well. I already ordered through hole parts so I can put them on breadboard first. It should be easy to test it, all I need is to measure the voltage in(lowest) and out, like you did and see if they match. Eventually I can add some resistors to make them match but I believe they will match. Thank you!

Comment: @Jens Well, you learn something new every day. In fig 11 they do indeed call it an opamp. I guess the external large cap is basically dominant pole compensation. I'd never considered using a 339 in this way. It does solve the diode drop problem and save components neatly. Now, will it simplify the circuit for which this configuration was originally created, which is the amplifiers configured differentially to pick the lowest voltage cell from a LiPo battery via the balance connector?

Comment: @Neil_UK Interesting idea, looks viable at a first glance. The offset error of LM339 is suboptimal in a battery context but OK for a simple undervoltage lockout. I will try two instances of the classic 4 resistor diff amp, connect the outputs and give it a run.

Answer (score 3):

It uses a lot of components, but I think it fulfills your requirement. Or maybe it's not a lot - one diode, one resistor and 1/4 of an opamp package per thermistor.

This only works if the motherboard uses an ADC to measure the voltage. They often measure chip voltages, and the OP's circuit is capable of generating a voltage, so that's a reasonable supposition. However, it's still possible to measure that thermistor in other ways, perhaps charging and discharging a capacitor and measuring timing, which this circuit won't handle.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fCBd9t.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Each thermistor generates a voltage with its corresponding resistor, reproducing the voltage that the motherboard expects to see.

Only the lowest voltage channel will control the output voltage through its diode. Opamp feedback removes the effect of the diode voltage drop, rather like it's used in a precision rectifier circuit. Thermistors generating a higher voltage will have their op-amp output at positive rail, with their diode reverse biassed.

You'll notice I've not specified the voltage rails for these opamps. If the thermistor voltage never drops below a volt or thereabouts, and you use a rail2rail or single supply opamp that can drive to close to its negative supply, then you will get away with powering it from GND as the negative rail. Diode leakage is not important in this circuit, so you could use schottky diodes instead of silicon to get down to 0.5 V output with a R2R opamp. Otherwise you'll need a negative supply. Positive rail needs to be at least Vref, or more depending on how high the output voltage is required to go.

Comment: Note that, if the source impedance can be rather high, the op-amps can be removed, just use the diodes from a much larger (100s k, megs?) pullup to each thermistor divider; completely passive. Conversely, if a low impedance is required, a forth amp should buffer the output, after the pull-up. (Less than 5k seems unlikely to be needed, given the original case; again, excepting for those possible weird use cases.)

Comment: @TimWilliams I'd need to see a circuit. How do you handle the diode drops without introducing a large temperature offset into the reading?

Comment: Nevermind -- I see VREF in OP's case is 2.048V, which leaves little room even for schottky diodes. Can be an option at higher voltages, but such is not the case here.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I'm not sure if this will work to my situation. Like I said "my motherboard have one connector" and the thermistor connects to that. The 10k resistor is soldered to MB. If can't easily get the Vref then this will not work.

Comment: It does not matter if it uses many components. I'm not going to commercially sell it. There will be one pcb therefore 5 component or 50 does not make too much difference.

Comment: I think the voltage drops at 75 C to about 300mV

Comment: @Chris In that case, you'll need to use the PC -5 V power supply for the amplifier negative rail, unless you're happy to clamp at 75 C, in which case you might just get there with power schottky diodes and a R2R amplifier to GND.

Comment: What about using LM339? It has open collector output, so no diodes required.

Comment: @Chris You could add a second voltage reference with the same value. I assume, the introduced error is not significant. It shoud be possible to keep the mainboard NTC where it is, using this circuit.

Comment: @Jens It's generally a good idea to use opamps where you have feedback and need closed loop stability, and a comparator when you have an open loop function. It's not guranteed, or even expected, that a comparator would be stable when fed back like that. It might be possible to stabilise it with some development.

Comment: @Neil_UK I agree, but LM339 can be used like an OpAmp. The open loop gain is 200k and if you look at the internal schematic, it basically is an OpAmp, no positive feedback inside. I just tested this circuit, no oscillation or stability problem.

Comment: @Jens Perhaps you could post a link to a gain/phase plot for the 339?

Comment: I don't think I can easily get Vref and -5V. I rather prefer a more complex solution using just 5V since a pasive one is not possible. I don't know much about op-amp. Maybe it can be used with 5V only.

Comment: A RRIO amp like TLV2374 will run at 5V or 3.3V just fine.  The diode drop is another matter, though. Is there a precision rectifier circuit that uses shunting rather than pass action? I'm not familiar with one if so. Alas, an MCU may well be the easiest solution...

Comment: @Tim Williams Please post a schematic if you can

Comment: @Tim Williams What is MCU? google say Marvel Cinematic Universe

Comment: @Chris Micro-Controller Unit, i.e. the chip in an Arduino, etc.

Comment: @Neil_UK I was unable to create a useful bode plot for this circuit. All I could see is a strong pole at or above 10 MHz with full phase reversal. The soldered circuit produces ~1 MHz sawtooth with jitter without a heavy load capacitor. So, I admit: It is not an OpAmp.