# Relay/Mosfet circuit for outputting source of highest voltage?

Tags: mosfet, relay, voltage-divider, thermistor, comparison

Currently using ntc thermistors to measure temperatures, I’m then using a comparison circuit to filter through a set of 3 thermistor-passed voltages (outputting the highest voltage).For overall design, I need to output the source of the highest voltage (basically outputting the thermistor signal alone so that I can use that as an input elsewhere). I believe this can be done using a system of relays or mosfets that would basically allow current to only flow from the highest voltage producing thermistor. I’m just unsure on how that would work.

Example sequence:
Thermistor 2 (T2) is at the highest temperature thus producing a higher output voltage. This voltage is compared to that of passing through T1 and T3. We output the voltage through T2. Now I want to have relays open for T1 and T3 so that those signals are not outputted. T2 now has a closed relay thus T2 us outputted.

General idea:[image]

Comment: look at the Q/A https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/390355/pick-largest-of-several-voltages-with-analogue-comparators, shows how to pick the highest of several analogue voltages for output with an IC and a few diodes - for some reason, the circuit schematic is 404, so I can't be bothered to write it as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the final circuit just needs a voltage as input, and doesn't expect to independently excite/control the current through the chosen thermistor, then I would use a small microcontroller with 3 ADC channels and 1 DAC channel.

Have a simple loop to do regular conversions on the three input thermistors, determine which thermistor to use, and then output the relevant voltage.

Answer (score 0):

The diodes ensure, that each OpAmp OA1-OA3 can pull up the voltage across R1 but is unable to lower it.

Each OpAmp will produce an output signal, that tries to make IN- equal to IN+. So the maximum of the 3 input voltages can be seen across R1.

OA4 is just a buffer to isolate the voltage at R1 from the output load.

There is a minimum voltage because the OpAmp output cannot go below 20..40 mV.

There is also a maximum voltage, defined by the OpAmp input voltage range, typically 1.5 V below the supply voltage.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f9bqap.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: LM324s might not be suitable for this, as temperature measurements usually involve pretty low voltages (though higher for thermistors than thermocouples).